# Problems about parameters configures of Herrmann and May's method to solve linear modular equation

Tags: rsa

I'm reading Herrmann and May's [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-89255-7_25); they introduced a method to solve multivariate linear equation modulo unknown divisors.

It's shown in Table 1 that, for an 512-bit RSA modulus N with divisor p of
size $p \geq N^{1/2}$, experiment with two blocks, each for an 45 bits unknown, yields $m = 15$.

But according to what they mentioned previously, define $$X_1 X_2 := N^{3\beta - 2 + 2(1 - \beta)^{3/2} - \epsilon}$$

and fix

$$m = \lceil{\frac{3\beta(1 + \sqrt{1 - \beta})}{\epsilon}}\rceil$$

I figured out that $\epsilon = 0.030955, \space m = 83$, which are far from their results.

What's wrong with my parameters, or did I miss something?